# Type mismatch on abstract type used in pattern matching

Tags: scala, generics

This code compiles with an error:

```
def f1[T](e: T): T = e match {
  case i:Int => i
  case b:Boolean => b
}
// type mismatch;
// found   : i.type (with underlying type Int)
// required: T
// case i:Int => i ...
```

And this code implementing GADT looks pretty identical from type checking perspective, but compiles without error:

```
sealed trait Expr[T]
case class IntExpr(i: Int) extends Expr[Int]
case class BoolExpr(b: Boolean) extends Expr[Boolean]

def eval[T](e: Expr[T]): T = e match {
  case IntExpr(i) => i
  case BoolExpr(b) => b
}
```

In both cases inside pattern matching expression we know that **i** and **b** are **Int** and **Boolean**. Why compilation failed on first example and succeeded on the second one?

Comment: I removed my answer (it's wrong). I also found that if you remove the explicit return type from your example it compiles and runs. If it had been a case of `C++` pre `C++17` (with compile-time generics, but without compile-time `if`) I would have told that the method body is not correct for any type `T`, as `T` is never both `Int` and `Boolean`.

Comment: @bobah that's cos it infers a return type of AnyVal

Comment: your function as is is just `def f1[T](e: T) = e`. If you want a solution, context would be helpful. Though perhaps you're just after a why

Comment: @JoelBerkeley The question is mainly theoretical than practical. I'm trying to understand compilation logic.

Comment: @JoelBerkeley how about `{ case i: Int => i+1; case b: Boolean => !b}`? :D

Comment: @Dima yes - in which the compiler error doesn't mention i.type, but Int - so we can surmise that singleton types aren't the cause

Comment: This seems to be dependent on the pattern being a value pattern or a type pattern. This fails as well  `case class Expr[T](v: T);  def eval[T](e: Expr[T]): T = e match {
    case Expr(i: Int) => i;
    case Expr(b: Boolean) => b
  }`

Comment: I think it depends on the constraints and the fact that the compiler should be able to prove that your function is able to return the same type for all inputs. Hopefully someone answers but in the meantime this might be helpful: https://users.scala-lang.org/t/dry-matching-generic-types-of-a-specific-type/1644

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first case is unsound because you underestimate the variety of types in Scala type system. It would make sense if, when we took `case i:Int` branch we knew `T` was `Int`, or at least a supertype of `Int`. But it doesn't have to be! E.g. it could be [42.type](https://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/42.type.html) or a [tagged type](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Tagged+type.html).

There's no such problem in the second case, because from `IntExpr <: Expr[T]`, the compiler *does* know `T` must be exactly `Int`.

Answer (score 2):

You ask of your function to return a type `T`, then you pattern-match against `Int` and `Boolean`. 
Except your function has no evidence that `Int` and `Boolean` are also of type `T`: when you pattern-match, [you introduce the constraint](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/08-pattern-matching.html#type-parameter-inference-for-constructor-patterns) that `Int <: T` and `Boolean <: T`.
You could either replace the return type `T` by a fixed type like `String` and return a String, or introduce a constraint that will satisfy both the case `Int` and `Boolean`.

```
//this compiles
def f1[T](e: T ): String = e match {
  case _:Int => "integer"
  case _:Boolean => "boolean"
}

//this compiles too, but will return AnyVal
def f1[T >: AnyVal](e: T ): T = e match {
   case i:Int => i
   case b:Boolean => b
}
```

Basically you can't just return any type `T` dynamically because you need to prove at compile time that your function type-checks out.

The other function in your example avoids the issue by encapsulating type constraints within case classes `IntExpr <: Expr[Int]` and `BoolExpr <: Expr[Boolean]` (notice how `Expr[_]` would be the equivalent of `T` in the constraints I mentioned above). At compile time, T is properly identified in all `case`s (e.g in the `IntExpr` you *know* it's an `Int`)

Comment: He matches `e`, which is of type `T`. Consider the second example in the question, `case IntExpr(i) => i` _does compile_, while `case i: Int => i` does not. 
The question is what is the difference

Comment: "Your function has no evidence" - do you mean the compiler can't work it out? After all, the evidence is there, in the match cases (granted perhaps you'd need an exhaustive match with `case e => e`). It would be a shame to have to lose type-checking on calls to f1 with Any.

Comment: Int an Boolean have a common supertype, namely `AnyVal`. The compiler could infer `T` to be `AnyVal`

Comment: @joel Yes, the problem is in the return type of the function. I tried to offer a solution to your issue.

Comment: @fusion if it did that, anytime you have type issues, it would fall back to AnyVal: I like types to catch errors early, not sure this would help

Comment: @joel fair enough, tried to adjust the answer accordingly

Comment: "You can't just return type T dynamically due to type erasure". 
This is not true. The second example in the question does exactly that.

Comment: True - long day T_T. Fixed.

Comment: @Esardes thanks for your answer. Especially for the link to scala spec. It did answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Esardes answer, this worked by defining a type bound for `T`:

```
scala> def f1[T >: AnyVal](e: T):T = e match {
     |   case i:Int => i
     |   case b:Boolean => b
     | }
f1: [T >: AnyVal](e: T)T

scala> f1(1)
res3: AnyVal = 1

scala> f1(true)
res4: AnyVal = true
```