# Why can't I return a concrete subtype of A if a generic subtype of A is declared as return parameter?

Tags: scala, generics, tree, pattern-matching, type-bounds

```
abstract class IntTree
object Empty extends IntTree
case class NonEmpty(elem: Int, left: IntTree, right: IntTree) extends IntTree

def assertNonNegative[S <: IntTree](t: S): S = {
  t match {
    case Empty => Empty  // type mismatch, required: S, found: Empty.type
    case NonEmpty(elem, left, right) =>
      if (elem < 0) throw new Exception
      else NonEmpty(elem, assertNonNegatve(left), assertNonNegative(right)) // req: S, fd: NonEmpty.type
  }
}
```

This is my failed attempt of implementing the function with signature `def assertNonNegative[S <: IntTree](t: S): S`. Other than changing the signature to `def assertNonNegative(t: IntTree): IntTree`, I couldn't find a way to implement it.

**Relevance of example:**
In a video about subtyping and generics(4.4) in the course "Functional Programming Principles in Scala", Martin Odersky uses practically the same example (IntSet instead of IntTree) and says that this signature can be used to express that the function takes Empty to Empty and NonEmpty to NonEmpty. He says that the other signature is fine in most situations but if needed, the one with upper bounded S can be a more precise option. However, he does not show an implementation of the function.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The compiler can not prove that in the case of `t` being **Empty** then it is because `S =:= Empty.type`. It may be fixed, but why? Are you sure you will even have a variable of type **NonEmpty**, you probably will have a variable of type **IntTree**.

Comment: Yes, I do not have a good reason to use the signature that returns S. When Martin said I could use it in this case, I just wanted to understand it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Method's right hand side (pattern matching)

```
t match {
  case Empty => Empty 
  case NonEmpty(elem, left, right) =>
    if (elem < 0) throw new Exception
    else NonEmpty(elem, assertNonNegatve(left), assertNonNegative(right)) 
}
```

means to check at runtime whether `t` is an instance of class `Empty$` (object `Empty`) and then choose the first branch or otherwise whether `t` is an instance of class `NonEmpty` and then choose the second branch.

Signature

```
def assertNonNegative[S <: IntTree](t: S): S
```

means to check at compile time that for every type `S`, which is a subtype of type `IntTree`, if the method accepts parameter `t` of type `S` then the method returns a value of type `S`.

The code doesn't compile because definition of the method doesn't correspond to its signature. Subclasses of `IntTree` are `NonEmpty` and `Empty` (object). If `IntTree` is not sealed you can create its subclasses different from `Empty` and `NonEmpty`, you can even create them dynamically at runtime. But let's even suppose that `IntTree` is sealed and `Empty` and `NonEmpty` are its only subclasses.

The thing is that there are a lot of subtypes of `IntTree` (classes and types are [different](https://typelevel.org/blog/2017/02/13/more-types-than-classes.html)): `IntTree`, `Empty.type`, `NonEmpty`, `Nothing`, `Null`, `Empty.type with NonEmpty`, `NonEmpty with SomeType`, `Empty.type with SomeType`, `IntTree with SomeType`, `T` (`type T <: IntTree`), `x.type` (`val x: IntTree = ???`) etc. and for all of them condition `(t: S): S` must be fulfilled.

Obviously it's not true. For example we can take `t = Empty.asInstanceOf[Empty.type with Serializable]`. It has type `Empty.type with Serializable`. At runtime it matches class `Empty` (object) so the first branch is selected. But at compile time we don't know this yet, how can you guarantee at compile time that both `Empty` and `NonEmpty` that are returned have type `Empty.type with Serializable`?

[Type mismatch on abstract type used in pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52479695/type-mismatch-on-abstract-type-used-in-pattern-matching)

One way to fix `assertNonNegative` is to write honest monomorphic

```
def assertNonNegative(t: IntTree): IntTree = {
  t match {
    case Empty => Empty
    case NonEmpty(elem, left, right) =>
      if (elem < 0) throw new Exception
      else NonEmpty(elem, assertNonNegative(left), assertNonNegative(right))
  }
}
```

another is to pretend that polymorphic signature is correct

```
def assertNonNegative[S <: IntTree](t: S): S = {
  (t match {
    case Empty => Empty
    case NonEmpty(elem, left, right) =>
      if (elem < 0) throw new Exception
      else NonEmpty(elem, assertNonNegative(left), assertNonNegative(right))
  }).asInstanceOf[S]
}
```

the third is to use type tags

```
def assertNonNegative[S <: IntTree : TypeTag](t: S): S = {
  t match {
    case Empty if typeOf[S] == typeOf[Empty.type] => Empty.asInstanceOf[S]
    case NonEmpty(elem, left, right) if typeOf[S] == typeOf[NonEmpty] =>
      if (elem < 0) throw new Exception
      else NonEmpty(elem, assertNonNegative(left), assertNonNegative(right)).asInstanceOf[S]
    case _ => ???
  }
}
```

the fourth is to make ADT more type-level

```
sealed trait IntTree
object Empty extends IntTree
case class NonEmpty[L <: IntTree, R <: IntTree](elem: Int, left: L, right: R) extends IntTree
```

and define type class

```
def assertNonNegative[S <: IntTree](t: S)(implicit ann: AssertNonNegative[S]): S = ann(t)

trait AssertNonNegative[S <: IntTree] {
  def apply(t: S): S
}
object AssertNonNegative {
  implicit val empty: AssertNonNegative[Empty.type] = { case Empty => Empty }
  implicit def nonEmpty[L <: IntTree : AssertNonNegative, 
                        R <: IntTree : AssertNonNegative]: AssertNonNegative[NonEmpty[L, R]] = {
    case NonEmpty(elem, left, right) =>
      if (elem < 0) throw new Exception
      else NonEmpty(elem, assertNonNegative(left), assertNonNegative(right))
  }
}
```

[Soundness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness) of type system means that sometimes we reject some programs at compile time, while they can't go wrong at runtime. For example

```
val x: Int = if (true) 1 else "a"
```