# How can I return a subclass of a type from a method with a generic, bounded type?

Tags: scala, generics, pattern-matching, scala-2

Given the below example, how can I make the code compile without resorting to casting in `myMethod`?

```
object Test {
  sealed trait MyTrait
  case class A(v: Int) extends MyTrait
  case class B(v: Int) extends MyTrait

  def myMethod[T <: MyTrait](in0: T): T = {
    in0 match {
      case in: A => in.copy(v = 1)
      case in: B => in.copy(v = 2)
    }
  }

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your code is correct this is just a limitation on the GADT support for the language, newer versions of the compiler usually handle this better. I also recall that moving the method to a different object in a different file seemed to fix the limitation in some cases.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61668592/why-cant-i-return-a-concrete-subtype-of-a-if-a-generic-subtype-of-a-is-declared

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez This is not GADT, just ADT. The behavior is the same in Scala 2.13 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/Oo6nmn1eSXKhaELOk7A15g/1 and Scala 3 https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/Oo6nmn1eSXKhaELOk7A15g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to:

- create some evidence which would transform your current type into T
- initiate it with an `identity`
- somehow make Scala

  - on one hand adjust input type to the same things as you `in` value
  - keep this evidence paired to whatever is matched

For instance you could implement it like this

```
import scala.annotation.nowarn

sealed trait MyTrait
case class A(v: Int) extends MyTrait
case class B(v: Int) extends MyTrait

@nowarn
def myMethod[T <: MyTrait](in0: T): T = {
  case class IntoT[A, B](value: A, upcast: A => B)
  IntoT(in0, identity[T]) match {
    case IntoT(in : A, upcastA: (A => T)) => upcastA(in.copy(v = 1))
    case IntoT(in : B, upcastB: (B => T)) => upcastB(in.copy(v = 2))
  }
}
```

It will make mismatching types error go away. Instead you will get warning that

```
match may not be exhaustive.

It would fail on pattern case: IntoT(_, _)
```

which in turn could be suppressed with `@nowarn`.

However, to be honest in such cases when I know that I know better than the compiler - because code is trivial and obvious at a glance, and I also cover it with tests - `.asInstanceOf` is not that bad. Sometimes you cannot avoid it so it's good to create some small, well tested utility which will help to deal with all cases where compiler was not so smart.

Comment: Is `match { case IntoT(in : A, upcastA: Function1[A, T])` the same as `match { case IntoT(in : A, upcastA: Function1[_, _])` because of type erasure?

Comment: Yeah, casting isn't the worst thing in the world but it's nice to avoid it if possible. I was just hoping there would be some neat trick that I had missed :)

Comment: @DmytroMitin probably yes, I think you'd have to work much harder to avoid that. I guess much harder that it's worth.

Answer (score 0):

How about [this one](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/6V9txzlEQZeiO6uKJxUpoQ):

```
object Test {
  sealed trait MyTrait[T]{
    def copy(v: Int): T
  }
  case class A(v: Int) extends MyTrait[A]
  case class B(v: Int) extends MyTrait[B]

  def myMethod[T <: MyTrait[T]](in0: T): T = {
    in0 match {
      case _: A => in0.copy(v = 1)
      case _: B => in0.copy(v = 2)
    }
  }

}
```

And there is [another solution](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BJJMzr4QRUOQaUxoOO5L0A):

```
object Test {
  
  trait MyTrait
  case class A(v: Int) extends MyTrait
  case class B(v: Int) extends MyTrait

  import scala.language.reflectiveCalls
  def myMethod[T <: MyTrait](in: {def copy(v: Int): T}): T = in match {
      case _: A => in.copy(v = 1)
      case _: B => in.copy(v = 2)
  }
  val a: A = myMethod(A(1))
    val b: B = myMethod(B(2))
}
```

Comment: Yes, that works but requires updating the type with a specialized solution for the use case. I was looking for something more generic and less intrusive. Thanks though.

Comment: @tjarvstrand I have edited my answer to add another solution using structural type.