# How can I verify type existence on compile time in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, types, pattern-matching, shapeless

I have the following traits and classes:

```scala
sealed trait Signal

sealed trait Description[T]

final case class S1(name: String) extends Signal

final case class D1(name: String) extends Description[S1]
```

What I try to achieve is that anyone who wants to add Signal will have (at compile time) to create a description.

I don't want to change the signature of `Description` but for sure not of `Signal`

I set my compiler to fail on warning, so I can leverage the fact that my ADT is sealed.

My idea was to have such a "compilation guard":

```scala
def compilationGuard[S <: Signal](s: S): Description[S] = s match { case S1(name) => D1(name) }
```

but I get the following error:

```
<console>:17: error: type mismatch;
 found   : D1
 required: Description[S]
       def compilationGuard[S <: Signal](s: S): Description[S] = s match { case S1(name) => D1(name) }
                                                                                              ^
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def compilationGuard[S <: Signal](s: S): Description[S] = s match { case S1(name) => D1(name) }
```

can't compile for the same reason as

```
def returnItself[S <: Signal](s: S): S = s match { case S1(name) => S1(name) }
```

Reasons are explained here in details:

[Why can't I return a concrete subtype of A if a generic subtype of A is declared as return parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61668592/why-cant-i-return-a-concrete-subtype-of-a-if-a-generic-subtype-of-a-is-declared)

[Type mismatch on abstract type used in pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52479695/type-mismatch-on-abstract-type-used-in-pattern-matching)

If you don't want to mix `Description` logic to ADT or define instances of a type class like `SignalMapper` manually you can use Shapeless

```
import shapeless.ops.coproduct.Mapper
import shapeless.{:+:, CNil, Coproduct, Generic, Poly1}

def compilationGuard[C <: Coproduct]()(implicit
  gen: Generic.Aux[Signal, C],
  mapper: Mapper[uniqueDescriptionPoly.type, C]
) = null

object uniqueDescriptionPoly extends Poly1 {
  implicit def cse[S <: Signal, C1 <: Coproduct](implicit
    gen1: Generic.Aux[Description[S], C1],
    ev: C1 <:< (_ :+: CNil)
  ): Case.Aux[S, Null] = null
}

compilationGuard()
```

Testing:

```
final case class S1(name: String) extends Signal
final case class S2(name: String) extends Signal
final case class D1(name: String) extends Description[S1] 
// doesn't compile

final case class S1(name: String) extends Signal
final case class S2(name: String) extends Signal
final case class D1(name: String) extends Description[S1]
final case class D2(name: String) extends Description[S1]
// doesn't compile

final case class S1(name: String) extends Signal
final case class S2(name: String) extends Signal
final case class D1(name: String) extends Description[S1]
final case class D2(name: String) extends Description[S2]
// compiles
```

Comment: this seems not to compile:
```
could not find implicit value for parameter gen: shapeless.Generic.Aux[Signal,C]
compilationGuard()
```

Comment: @NoamShaish The following code compiles https://scastie.scala-lang.org/YDGlShJdTq6j76zIJO43bQ

Comment: Can you please help me understand why this does not compile:
https://scastie.scala-lang.org/RwBjDWGnQJij3gcZLP0AuQ

Comment: @NoamShaish Trait `Description` must be sealed (as well as `Signal`).

Comment: One small side question how could I improve the implicit error message.
I tried using  ```@implicitNotFound("Cannot find Description of ${T}")``` on compilationGuard but this doesnt seems to work. Thanks again

Comment: @NoamShaish `@implicitNotFound` [can annotate](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/annotation/implicitNotFound.scala#L15-L55) a class or implicit parameter, not method. So either do `def compilationGuard[C <: Coproduct]()(
      implicit
      gen: Generic.Aux[Signal, C],
      @implicitNotFound("No unique Description for all children of Signal") mapper: Mapper[uniqueDescriptionPoly.type, C]
    ) = null` or create a type class and annotate it.

Comment: Once again thanks, it didnt work on the parameter but I solved it by declaring a type alias 
```@implicitNotFound("No unique Description for all children of Signal")
  type MapperC[C <: Coproduct] = Mapper[uniqueDescriptionPoly.type, C]```
and updating compilationGuard accordingly

Comment: @NoamShaish Yeah, annotating type alias is also an option. Annotating implicit parameters works starting from 2.13.0 https://github.com/scala/scala/releases/tag/v2.13.0 "Support implicitNotFound on parameters (#6340)"

Answer (score 2):

> What I try to achieve is that anyone who wants to add Signal will have (at compile time to create a description.

The easy way to do so is to make it part of `Signal`:

```
sealed trait Signal[S <: Signal[S, D], D <: Description[S]] {
  // optionally
  def description: D
}

final case class S1(name: String) extends Signal[S1, D1] {
  def description = D1(name)
}
```

or

```
sealed trait Signal[S <: Signal[S]] {
  type Descr <: Description[S]
  // optionally
  def description: Descr
}

final case class S1(name: String) extends Signal[S1] {
  type Descr = D1
  def description = D1(name)
}
```

Of course it isn't far from the simpler

```
sealed trait Signal[S <: Signal] {
  def description: Description[S]
}
```

depending on your requirements.

Comment: Thats mixing logic into my ADT which I would like to avoid so Signal is pure ADT that can be loaded from files with tools like pureconfig

Answer (score 2):

Your program is failing, because it can't prove, that type `S` is `S1`.

Instead of doing pattern matching, you could introduce typeclass which would do a mapping on compile time:

```
trait SignalMapper[S] { //typeclass handling of mapping S to D
  type D <: Description[S]

  def map(signal: S): D
}

//instance of typeclass SignalMapper for S1
//if you'd put it in a companion object of S1, it would be always in scope
object S1 { 

  implicit val mapperS1: SignalMapper[S1] = new SignalMapper[S1] {
    type D = D1

    def map(signal: S1) = D1(signal.name)
  }

}
```

Then you can rewrite compilationGuard as:

```
def compilationGuard[S <: Signal](s: S)(implicit mapper: SignalMapper[S]): Description[S] = mapper.map(s)
```

[Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/xVd89IJjSxahKo68ArEQwg)

Comment: The problem with that approach is that it will only fail compilation on usage of compilationGuard with the new type.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: This wont fail if there is no call for compilationGuard with all types.
If there will be no call like:
```scala
compilationGuard(S2("hello"))
```
it will not fail