# Scala: Verify Unique Type Existence At Compile Time

Tags: scala, generics, types, shapeless

I have the following:

```scala
sealed trait Tag
case object MyTag1 extends Tag
case object MyTag2 extends Tag

sealed trait Error[T <: Tag]

// error implementations...
```

I'd like for two `Error` implementations using the same `Tag` to fail at compile time, but not fail in the case there are `Tag`s without an associated `Error`.

The compilation guard given in the first answer here: [How can I verify type existence on compile time in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61723759/how-can-i-verify-type-existence-on-compile-time-in-scala) comes very close to what I want, but fails at compile time if there exists a `Tag` without an associated `Error`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add one more case to the `Poly`

```scala
def compilationGuard[C <: Coproduct]()(implicit
  gen: Generic.Aux[Signal, C],
  mapper: Mapper[uniqueDescriptionPoly.type, C]
) = null

object uniqueDescriptionPoly extends Poly1 {
  implicit def cse[S <: Signal, C1 <: Coproduct](implicit
    gen1: Generic.Aux[Description[S], C1],
    ev: C1 <:< (_ :+: CNil)
  ): Case.Aux[S, Null] = null

  implicit def cse0[S <: Signal, C1 <: Coproduct](implicit
    gen1: Refute[Generic[Description[S]]]
  ): Case.Aux[S, Null] = null
}

compilationGuard()
```

```scala
final case class S1(name: String) extends Signal
final case class S2(name: String) extends Signal
final case class D1(name: String) extends Description[S1]
//compiles
```

```scala
final case class S1(name: String) extends Signal
final case class S2(name: String) extends Signal
final case class D1(name: String) extends Description[S1]
final case class D2(name: String) extends Description[S1]
// doesn't compile
```

```scala
final case class S1(name: String) extends Signal
final case class S2(name: String) extends Signal
final case class D1(name: String) extends Description[S1]
final case class D2(name: String) extends Description[S2]
// compiles
```