# Type parameter circumvents match exhaustivity warning

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, compiler-warnings, type-parameter, non-exhaustive-patterns

Why does type parameter bound by sealed type seem [not](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/0G1FXtpDS5uZBSPWjCzsCA) to raise exhaustivity warning

```
sealed trait A
case class B() extends A
case class C(i: Option[Int]) extends A

def f[T <: A](a: T) =
  a match {
    case B() =>
    case C(None) =>
  }

f(C(Some(42))) // throws MatchError
```

whilst without type parameter

```
def f(a: A) =
  a match {
    case B() =>
    case C(None) =>
  }
```

the warning is raised

```
warning: match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following input: C(Some(_))
    a match {
    ^
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pattern matching

```
def f[T <: A](a: T) =
  a match {
    case B() =>
    case C(None) =>
  }
```

can be exhaustive or not exhaustive depending on `T`.

(`T <: A` doesn't mean that `T` is `B` or `C`, see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61668592/why-cant-i-return-a-concrete-subtype-of-a-if-a-generic-subtype-of-a-is-declared) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52479695/type-mismatch-on-abstract-type-used-in-pattern-matching) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61782582/type-bound-in-scala-function-complicates-piping-to-method-reference)).

According to [specification](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html)

> If the selector of a pattern match is an instance of a sealed class, the compilation of pattern matching can emit warnings which diagnose that a given set of patterns is not exhaustive, i.e. that there is a possibility of a `MatchError` being raised at run-time.

So compiler **can** but not **must** emit warning.