# General-purpose method that returns a union type

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, typeclass, implicit, union-types

I have a union type Int and String from [Union type Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508077/how-to-define-type-disjunction-union-types) and I want to add it to general-purpose method. Could u help me to write this method, without compile error.

```
object OrTypeMain extends App {

  class StringOrInt[T]
  object StringOrInt {
    implicit object IntWitness    extends StringOrInt[Int]
    implicit object StringWitness extends StringOrInt[String]
  }

  object Bar {
    def foo[T: StringOrInt](x: T): Unit = x match {
      case _: String => println("str")
      case _: Int => println("int")
    }

    // target method
    def reverse[T: StringOrInt](x: T): StringOrInt = x match { // not compile
    def reverse[T: StringOrInt](x: T): T = x match { // not compile too

      case x: String => x + "new"
      case y: Int => y + 5
    }
  }

  Bar.reverse(123)
  Bar.reverse("sad")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why `reverse` doesn't compile is explained here:

[Why can't I return a concrete subtype of A if a generic subtype of A is declared as return parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61668592/why-cant-i-return-a-concrete-subtype-of-a-if-a-generic-subtype-of-a-is-declared/)

[Type mismatch on abstract type used in pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52479695/type-mismatch-on-abstract-type-used-in-pattern-matching)

Replace runtime pattern matching with compile-time type class. `StringOrInt` is already a type class. Just move your operations there.

```
trait StringOrInt[T] {
  def reverse(t: T): T
}    
object StringOrInt {
  implicit object IntWitness extends StringOrInt[Int] {
    override def reverse(t: Int): Int = t + 5
  }

  implicit object StringWitness extends StringOrInt[String] {
    override def reverse(t: String): String = t + "new"
  }  
}

def reverse[T: StringOrInt](x: T): T = implicitly[StringOrInt[T]].reverse(x)
```